# How to bind a process to a particular core in freebsd/linux

Tags: multicore

Is there any way to bind a process / (or a thread) to a particular core in FreeBSD//Linux
I googled could not find an answer. But people must be doing it and I am surprised that the answer is not easily available

Thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 3):

From the command line you can use `taskset`. From within your code you can use `sched_setaffinity`.

[$ man taskset](http://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset)
[$ man sched_setaffinity](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity)

Answer (score 0):

For FreeBSD you can also consider its following counterparties

[$ man cpuset(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&sektion=1&manpath=freebsd-release-ports)

[$ man cpuset(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=cpuset&sektion=2&manpath=FreeBSD%207.1-RELEASE)

There's a somehow [related topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/625146/difference-between-taskset-and-cpuset) on server fault to check